# Rails - Rspec - stub params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I created some public method in controller which does some work.

```
 def current_service
    service_name = params[:controller].gsub('api/v1/', '').gsub(%r{/.+}, '')
 end
```

I would like to test this method using RSpec but I dont't know how can I stub params. How should I do that?

Comment: This is a statement, not a question.

Comment: you are right, I added the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If this is a controller spec, you should be able to do something like this:

```
allow(controller).to receive(:params).and_return({controller: 'a value'})
```

Alternatively, move the `params[:controller]` statement to a separate method and stub that in your spec.

Comment: Great answer. My issue it was I used `described_class` instead of `controller` and it caused the error.  Thank you.

Comment: What about strong params testing?

Comment: thank you @codebeef - would you by chance know how to make this work with request specs?

Answer (score 5):

For strong parameters you can stub them as following:

```
params = ActionController::Parameters.new(foo: 'bar')
allow(controller).to receive(:params).and_return(params)
```